# datagridview error index out of range vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, oledb

I'm reading a column of integers from an excel spreadsheet into a datagridview and it's just not working. I've tried two ways, one way using a loop and the other way using OleDb. The code just before the troublesome line uses OleDb to fill another DGV with one column from excel perfectly, so I don't know why it doesn't work the second time. Here's what I got:

Method 1---

```
 Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & FormFile & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""")

        'Fill dataviewgrid1 with element symbols, string' THIS WORKS PERFECTLY!!
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & sheetname & "$A13:A" & lrow & "]", cn)
        ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        'Fill dataviewgrid2 with compositions, string' THIS DOESN"T WORK, AND I DONT GET ANY ERROR MESSAGES. NOTHING HAPPENS.
        da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & sheetname & "$B13:B" & lrow & "]", cn)
        ds2 = New System.Data.DataSet
        da2.Fill(ds2)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds2.Table
```

To reiterate above, filling dgv1 is successful. Filling dgv 2 is unsuccessful, and no errors pop up or anything. Here's the other way I tried:

Method 2:

```
DataGridView.ColumnCount = 1
For xrow As Integer = 13 To lrow - 1
            DataGridView.Rows.Add
            DataGridView2.Item(0, xrow - 13).Value = xlWsheet2.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
        Next
```

this gets me the error 'Index out of range'.

Why can't I get this to work?

Comment: Method 2 would require you add the blank rows before you try to address them. You will also have to manually add the destination column.

Comment: Thanks @rheitzman, I've done that and edited my post above. In DGV2, a cell IS created when I execute, but now I get a null ref exception on that same line (2nd-to-last line in method 2). I feel like we're on the right track...

Comment: The changes didn't make it into the post - you need to add code to add a column to the DGV and enough rows to accommodate the type of addressing you are using. Or add a column and use .Rows.Add(<object>) which will add a row with the data.

Comment: OK, so in making the edits of 'Rows.Add' and 'ColumnCount', I was able to get the DGR to populate, but only the last row, so....see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222886/datagridview-not-displaying-correctly-vb-net
Thanks for your help, @rheitzman!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer to correcting method 2, above. I didn't define xlWsheet2.

I'm still not sure why method 1 didn't work.